# copy column values from one column to other

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to copy data into one column (which is null for now) in table A from another similar column in table B. One condition I have is that I only want to copy values from the column in table B that is NOT NULL.

So far I have:

```
UPDATE a
    SET a.[null column] = b.[original column]
FROM A as a
INNER JOIN B as b
    ON a.id = b.idx
```

Any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE a 
INNER JOIN b AS b ON b.idx = a.id
SET a.column_name = b.column_name
WHERE a.column_name IN NULL
```

You can use a join like this. If there were schema it would be better

Answer (score 0):

```
.... where b.[original column] is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE a
SET a.[column] = b.[column]
FROM A as a
INNER JOIN B as b
on a.id = b.idx and b.[column] is not null
```